# How to add responsive image resizing to a sprite sheet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please note, this question is about responsive *resizing* (displaying alternate `width` and `height`) not responsive retina images achieved with `@media` queries.

I have a sprite sheet that I use to display images as background to `div` in my markup:

```
.sprite {
    background: url('../sprites/sprite-sheet.png') no-repeat top left;
    background-size: 1000px 200px;
    display: block;
}
```

The sprites themselves are not uniform in size and vary in dimension:

```
.sprite.sprite-1 { 
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
}

.sprite.sprite-2 { 
  background-position: 50px 65px;
  width: 225px;
  height: 325px;
}
```

Etc.

How can I add a responsive behaviour to each sprite, so that when its container is forced into a width smaller than its natural resolution, the image shrinks proportionately?

Bootstrap achieves this effect on standard `img` tags by adding `class="img-responsive"`. Can this effect also be realised on a sprite sheet?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/M55SY/

Comment: Yes, that effect, but with a sprite sheet. The approach there doesn't work with sprites at various background positions, as in the example

Comment: Don't do it, you will pull your hair out

Comment: would the `transform: scale (#,#);` property work in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

This is also done adding `media queries` at the desired break points

then your CSS would look like this

```
.sprite {
    background: url('../sprites/sprite-sheet.png') no-repeat top left;
    background-size: 1000px 200px;
    display: block;

    @media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
        /* Styles */
        background-size: 500px 100px;
       /* you can put whatever styles you need here . new image . new position . anything */
    }
}
```

they way i handle icons for mobile & desktop when i use sprite sheet is to add both big & small images in the sprite . and then point to a different image (inside the sprite) when hitting a breakpoint . background-size on sprite sheets gave me lots of problems ...

```
.sprite.sprite-1 { 
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) { /* breakpoint for tablet */
    /* Styles */
    background-posiiton: 250px 250px; /* position of big image inside spritesheet */
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to resize the sprite background position, height and width sizes?

Comment: do you understand what i did in the second piece of CSS ?

Comment: with the second approach NO . sprite width / height remain the same . because your just pointing to a different part of the same 'big image'